# Change .json file being placed into UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

The original file defined:

```
#define kBgQueue dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)
#define kLatestKivaLoansURL [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.myurl.com/.json"];
```

The data is fetched in:

```
- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {
```

...and assigned to the each cell in:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```

To change the file being used I tried this:

```
- (IBAction)subRedditChange:(id)sender
{
latestKivaLoansURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://reddit.com/r/aww.json"];
[self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

Nothing happens, the .json structure is identical in each file so fetchedData will work for both.

Comment: #define is for constants, not things you want to change. Use an instance variable for that.

Comment: I figured that out but I still don't understand how to fix the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#define is for constants, so you want to use a property instead:

```
@interface YOUR_CLASS
...
@property (strong, monatomic) NSURL *latestKivaLoansURL;
...
@end
```

Then, initially when you're setting up:

```
self.latestKivaLoansURL = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.myurl.com/.json"];
```

And later, when you want to change:

```
self.latestKivaLoansURL = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.newurl.json"];
```

Then re-fetch your data, using `self.latestKivaLoansURL` as the URL for the request.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to change the `url` at run time. You must create instance variable of `NSUrl`.

Define a `NSURL` instance `NSURL *url` in your `.h`.
And in your `.m` file override `viewDidLoad` method to set your `url`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
// 
self.url = [NSURL urlWithString: @"http://www.myurl.com/.json"];

}
```

and when you want to hit with some other url.

```
- (IBAction)subRedditChange:(id)sender
{
self.url = [NSURL urlWithString: @"http://www.myurl.com/.json"];
//Call Some method that fetch data from webservice 
[self.tableView reloadData];
}
```